# Output Json Array inside a PHP array

Tags: php, arrays, json

I am having a slight issue in optimizing my code to output the values in the Json Array stored inside a PHP array.

**This is the sample array**

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
    (
        [0] => ["string 1", "string 2", "string 3"]
    )

    [1] => Array
    (
        [0] => ["string 4", "string 5", "string 6"]
    )
    .....
)
```

**This is the code I am using and it works**

```
  $q = EstateTypes::query()->lists('column_value');

  $array1 = json_decode($q[0], true);
  $array2 = json_decode($q[1], true);
  $array3 = json_decode($q[2], true);

  foreach ($array1 as $key => $value) {
      echo $value . "<br>";
  }
   foreach ($array2 as $key => $value) {
      echo $value . "<br>";
  }
  foreach ($array3 as $key => $value) {
      echo $value . "<br>";
  }
```

I hope you see that the problem is this code is duplicating itself a lot. I've been trying to solve it properly but have been unable to. Would be glad for any help or further pointers on what I should do.

Comment: Can't you just use foreach for $q?

Comment: why so many foreach loops?

Comment: Try it again with one loop over `$q`

Comment: If i just use foreach, then it outputs the whole json array, not individual values. And if i put the $value in the json_decode() then it throws an error "array to string conversion"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$q = EstateTypes::query()->lists('column_value');

foreach($q as $item){
    $array = json_decode($item, true);
    foreach ($array as $value) {
        echo $value . "<br>";
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you! I will accept your answer as soon as I can